# Fetch error FABRIC_E_TIMEOUT for SwaggerUI/swagger.json

Tags: .net-core, swagger, azure-service-fabric, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am developing an Azure Service Fabric Service, in which I have used Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to build API List. I am using the following code in my Startup.cs file

In ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                 {
                      c.SwaggerDoc("Backend", new Info { Title = "My Backend", Version = "v1.0" });
                 });`
```

And in Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)

```
` app.UseSwagger(c => c.PreSerializeFilters
     .Add((swagger, httpReq) => swagger.Host = httpReq.Host.Value));

  app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/MyApp.Fabric/MyApp.Backend/swagger/Backend/swagger.json",
        "Backend"));`
```

Here, because I am developing SF service, I have used reverse proxy with swagger endpoint configuration. Now the same thing is working with my other services except one. I have the same code and same version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore nuget used in all of my services that is 3.0.0

When I try to access the SwaggerUI for this service, I am getting the following error

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this ? I have been trying but could not get any suitable solution..

Comment: This is clearly an access issue, make sure you can manually access that endpoint you have configured

Comment: No, I can not access this endpoint manually.

Comment: According to the error information, it indicate that can't load api definition. You could refer to this document [blog](https://appswin.co.th/2018/02/26/service-fabric-create-stateless-web-api-with-asp-net-core-and-generate-api-doc-with-swagger-io/) to config swagger in the service fabric project.

Comment: IF the swagger configuration is the same as your other services, and those are OK, this smells like something in Azure, maybe a routing issue on the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my case, when I dig the problem in more depth, I found in my APIs, there are some objects used which don't have any namespaces assigned. And somehow the runtime could not resolve the definitions for those objects which leads to a failure to load API definitions.

@Tom Sun, if you could post your comment as an answer, I will be able to mark it as answer. Thank you.